# Recursively read all folders with Fetchmail (Exchange Server)

Tags: exchange, fetchmail

I'm currently maintaining a project that relies on fetchmail to import e-mails from a given exchange mail-server, one of the accounts I'm pulling mail from is unfortunately set up with a lot of folders.

I found that I can use the `folder` directive in my `fetchmailrc` file, however this isn't recursive, as all other folders still have their emails marked as unread (and my script doesn't collect nearly as much data as I expect it to collect).

While fetchmail supports multiple folders, this won't work as **the mailbox gets changed regularly, meaning I can't hard-code all folders.** I looked online and found that some servers have an 'All Mail' type of folder, however I wasn't able to find this for Exchange.

Does anyone know how I could recursively fetch all mail using `fetchmail`? This is what my `fetchmailrc` looks like:

```
poll owa.example.com
protocol imap
auth password
user 'example@owa.example.com' with password 'password' mda "/home/user/parse-emails"
folder 'INBOX'
keep
```